# How to make the last item of the listview be at the top

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview with a bunch of items of different sizes

I have a button to scroll to a certain item in the listview

however, when this item is last, the listview of course stops when this item becomes visible

but I want the listview to scroll up in such a way that this last item is the only visible item on the screen - and the bottom of the list is blank

how do I do this?

my scroll method:

```
    public void scrollTo(int newPosition) {

    lv.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(newPosition+ 1, 0, 500);

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //this is needed in order for the item to be at the top
                     //because the listview stops, if scrolling from top down, and stops 
                     //once item becomes visible
            lv.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(newPoisition+ 1, 0, 0);
        }
    }, 501);

}
```

this is the crash report for adding a dummy item manually

[image]

Comment: what did u tried so far ? can u post ur code please

Comment: i just created a normal listview, with a normal base adapter that uses an arrayList to display its items

Comment: I thought of adding a dummy very tall item, but that wont work, because my items are placed in a certain way, and the listview crashes when it finds the dummy item

Comment: @JackKFouani added my scroll method

Comment: The only solution I see is to add a dummy item. It should work. If your app is crashing.. you are doing something wrong. Can you post how and where your app crashes on adding a dummy item?

Comment: It's maybe not a fancy way, but you could set a padding/marginBottom to your last item with the height of your ListView minus the height of your last row ?

Comment: @JackKFouani I do not want to change the order of my items, or add them, or remove them - i want to make it so when the end of the list is visible - i can scroll more until the last item on the list is show n at the top of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do this in the following way:

- Detect the end of the list view.
- When the list view reached the end, keep the last one in the list(array list that is used to populate the list) and the delete all others and refresh the list. If you do not want to delete them, simply copy to another array list and copy back the items, if the user needs to move up again.

To detect the end of the list view you can use the following class:

```
  public final class GVOnScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
       public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            if (loading) {
                if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                    loading = false;
                    previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                    offset++;
                }
            }

            if  (!loading && totalItemCount == (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) && (productCount > totalItemCount)) {
                productListServiceRequest();
                businessResultListView.setSelection(firstVisibleItem);
                loading = true;
                  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {

                     readyToRequest = true;         

                      }
              }, 2000);

                  readyToRequest = false;

            }

       }

    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

  }
```

and set it to the list view like:

```
listview.setAdapter(businessPromotionListAdapter);
```

With the above class, you can see:

- Number of items that you can see in the screen.
- Number of items that you have scrolled up.
- Total number of items in the list.

Comment: I do not want to add new items to the list - > i want it so when the list reaches the end, i can scroll more until the last item is at the top of the screen